# How can I loop this code ? Please help me

Tags: loops, math, sum, taylor-series

While the values of n increase in sequence, the value of n must be written to the Taylor series and display the sums in order. Could you help as early as possible? Could you show appropriate loops?

```
import math
x = 1.010
print("My x value is", format(x,".3f"))
math.cos(x)
print("Exact value of cos(x) =", math.cos(x))
math.exp(x)
print("Exact value of e^x =", math.exp(x),"\n")
print("The sum of two =", math.cos(x)+math.exp(x),"\n")
print("If the precision is 3 digits,", format(math.cos(x)+math.exp(x),".3f"))
n=0
num1=x**(2*n)
deno1=math.factorial(2*n)
taylor1= ((-1)**n)*(num1/deno1)
print(taylor1)
n=1
num1=x**(2*n)
deno1=math.factorial(2*n)
taylor2= ((-1)**n)*(num1/deno1)
print(taylor2)
n=2
num1=x**(2*n)
deno1=math.factorial(2*n)
taylor3= ((-1)**n)*(num1/deno1)
print(taylor3)
n=3
num1=x**(2*n)
deno1=math.factorial(2*n)
taylor4= ((-1)**n)*(num1/deno1)
print(taylor4)
sum_taylor=taylor1+taylor2+taylor3+taylor4
print("according to taylor series,cos(x) sum is",sum_taylor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
x = 1.010
print("My x value is", format(x,".3f"))
math.cos(x)
print("Exact value of cos(x) =", math.cos(x))
math.exp(x)
print("Exact value of e^x =", math.exp(x),"\n")
print("The sum of two =", math.cos(x)+math.exp(x),"\n")
print("If the precision is 3 digits,", format(math.cos(x)+math.exp(x),".3f"))

i = 3 #Max precision required
sum_taylor = 0
for n in range(i+1):
    num = x**(2*n)
    deno = math.factorial(2*n)
    taylor = ((-1)**n)*(num/deno)
    print(taylor)
    sum_taylor= sum_taylor + taylor
    
print("according to taylor series,cos(x) sum is",sum_taylor)
```